# copy tables from word without repeating header

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

```
Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
wdApp.Visible = True      ' Do show Word. 

For Each f In fo.Files
If f.Name Like "*.docx" And Left(f.Name, 2) <> "~$" Then
    Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(f.Path, False, True, Format:="doc Files")
    tableTot = wdDoc.Tables.Count
    If tableTot = 0 Then
        MsgBox "The file" & wdDoc.Name & "does not have invoice table", vbInformation, "Invoice sheet is invalid"
    End If


    Set xlwb = Workbooks.Add
    Set xlsh = xlwb.Sheets(1)
    Set rng = xlsh.Range("A1")
    xlsh.Activate

            For Each t In wdDoc.Tables
                t.Range.Copy
                rng.Select
                rng.Parent.PasteSpecial Format:="Text", Link:=False, _
                            DisplayAsIcon:=False
                With rng.Resize(t.Rows.Count, t.Columns.Count)
                    .Cells.UnMerge
                    .Cells.ColumnWidth = 14
                    .Cells.RowHeight = 14
                    .Cells.Font.Size = 10
                End With
            Set rng = rng.Offset(t.Rows.Count, 0)
            Next
            xlwb.SaveAs (excel_path & "\" & Replace(f.Name, ".docx", ".xlsx"))
            wdDoc.Close False
            xlwb.Close False
            Set t = Nothing: Set rng = Nothing: Set wdDoc = Nothing
            tableTot = 0
End If
Next
```

Hi, I am trying to create new excel sheets for all invoices from a given folder. But the invoice has many other text which are in small tables so it copies that too. 
Is there a way I can start my table based on keyword from a row (since the keyword column is also not constant) and pull my table without repeating the header in my excel file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could replace:

```
For Each t In wdDoc.Tables
  t.Range.Copy
  rng.Select
```

with:

```
h As Long: h = 0
For Each t In wdDoc.Tables
  With t
    If InStr(1, .Range.Text, "KeyWord", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
      If h > 0 Then .Rows(1).Delete
      .Range.Copy
      h = h + 1
    End If
  End With
```

or, if you don't want *any* header rows (you post isn't clear):

```
For Each t In wdDoc.Tables
  With t
    If InStr(1, .Range.Text, "KeyWord", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
      .Rows(1).Delete
      .Range.Copy
    End If
  End With
```

Comment: Thank you!,Yes I do need the first header row. But the tables in continuation of corresponding pages are also it which needs to be deleted. When I used your first comment (with) I am getting "Paste Special failed. On debugging ".Range.Text shows object variable was not set. Is there a way I can attach my word file here? Actually the Invoice file has many other tables like Invoice number, Name and others in table form apart from the main inventory table. I just want the main inventory table and two variables from the main section.

Comment: Presumably you're referring to 'rng.Parent.PasteSpecial Format:="Text", Link:=False, _ DisplayAsIcon:=False' - which is unaffected by the code I supplied. That said, you certainly don't need '.Parent'.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. My keyword (Description) is not found by Instr. I used *, cstr, Ucase... The word does show up in msgbox of .range.text but not getting inside the if loop. Thanks for your time and help,

Comment: Works for me, without the UCase conversion... Since you haven't supplied your UCase conversion code, I can't comment on its efficacy. I've revised the code so that the Instr test is not case-sensitive.

Comment: Cross-posted at: http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?67455-copy-tables-from-word-without-repeating-header. For cross-posting etiquette, please read: http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! it works perfect. God bless!